# Add html word before category

Tags: categories

I'm trying add "Tuppersex" text before categories but it's impossible! Everyone can help me please?

Now, final code is this:

```
<ul id="cat-col-1" class="cat_col">
<li class="cat-item cat-item-815">
<a title="" href="http://www.domain.com/1/">1</a>
</li>
```

But i want show:

```
<ul id="cat-col-1" class="cat_col">
<li class="cat-item cat-item-815">
<a title="" href="http://www.domain.com/1/"> Tuppersex 1</a>
</li>
```

How is possible?

```
<?php
$get_cats = wp_list_categories( 'echo=0&title_li=&depth=1&hide_empty=0&exclude=1,762,899,951' );
$cat_array = explode('</li>',$get_cats);
$results_total = count($cat_array);
$cats_per_list = ceil($results_total / 3);
$list_number = 1;
$result_number = 0;
?>

<ul class="cat_col" id="cat-col-<?php echo $list_number; ?>">

<?php
foreach($cat_array as $category) {
$result_number++;

if($result_number % $cats_per_list == 0) {
    $list_number++;
    echo $category.'</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="cat_col" id="cat-col-'.$list_number.'">';
}
else
    echo $category.'</li>';
}
?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add "Tuppersex" text before each category name, you can do it by jquery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  var catList = jQuery('.cat_col li a');
  catList.each(function(key, value){
    var data = jQuery(this).text();
    data = 'Tuppersex '+data;
    jQuery(this).text(data);
  });
});
```

Code: http://jsbin.com/AJuJeQi/1/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 0):

Like I said in the comment it's easier to do this with [`get_categories`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories), below some exemplary usage.

**Code:**

```
$cat_array = get_categories('parent=0&hide_empty=0&exclude=1,762,899,951');
$results_total = count($cat_array);
$cats_per_list = ceil($results_total / 3);
$list_number = 1;
$result_number = 0;

echo '<ul class="cat_col" id="cat-col-'.$list_number.'?>">';

foreach($cat_array as $category) {
    $result_number++;
    $category_link = get_category_link( $category->term_id);
    if($result_number % $cats_per_list == 0) {
        $list_number++;
        echo '<a href="'.esc_url( $category_link ).'" title="Tuppersex">';
        echo __( 'Tuppersex', 'your-text-domain' ) . ' ' . $category->name.'</li>';
        echo '</a>';
        echo '</ul>
        <ul class="cat_col" id="cat-col-'.$list_number.'">';
    } else {
        echo '<a href="'.esc_url( $category_link ).'" title="Tuppersex">';
        echo __( 'Tuppersex', 'your-text-domain' ) . ' ' . $category->name.'</li>';
        echo '</a>';
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

Instead of using the `depth` parameter you can use the `parent` parameter with a value of `0`, which has the result that only the top-level will be shown.

---

**2nd approach:**

Like we realized the depth parameter isn't working with above solution. After looking at the source it was obvious it can't, because it is used by [`walk_category_tree()`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.7.1/src/wp-includes/category-template.php#L731) in [`wp_list_categories()`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.7.1/src/wp-includes/category-template.php#L480). That step isn't part of [`get_categories`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories), because it doesn't construct any output. Because of that another logical solution for your problem is extending the [`Walker Class`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/Walker), namely the [`Walker_Category`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.7.1/src/wp-includes/category-template.php#L767) class.

**Code:**

```
class Custom_Cat_Walker extends Walker_Category {
    function start_el( &$output, $category, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0 ) {
        extract($args);

        $cat_name = esc_attr( $category->name );
        $cat_name = apply_filters( 'list_cats', $cat_name, $category );
        $link = '<a href="' . esc_url( get_term_link($category) ) . '" ';
        if ( $use_desc_for_title == 0 || empty($category->description) )
            $link .= 'title="' . esc_attr( sprintf(__( 'View all posts filed under %s' ), $cat_name) ) . '"';
        else
            $link .= 'title="' . esc_attr( strip_tags( apply_filters( 'category_description', $category->description, $category ) ) ) . '"';
        $link .= '>';
        $link .= __( 'Tuppersex', 'your-text-domain' ) . ' ' . $cat_name . '</a>';

        if ( !empty($feed_image) || !empty($feed) ) {
            $link .= ' ';

            if ( empty($feed_image) )
                $link .= '(';

            $link .= '<a href="' . esc_url( get_term_feed_link( $category->term_id, $category->taxonomy, $feed_type ) ) . '"';

            if ( empty($feed) ) {
                $alt = ' alt="' . sprintf(__( 'Feed for all posts filed under %s' ), $cat_name ) . '"';
            } else {
                $title = ' title="' . $feed . '"';
                $alt = ' alt="' . $feed . '"';
                $name = $feed;
                $link .= $title;
            }

            $link .= '>';

            if ( empty($feed_image) )
                $link .= $name;
            else
                $link .= "<img src='$feed_image'$alt$title" . ' />';

            $link .= '</a>';

            if ( empty($feed_image) )
                $link .= ')';
        }

        if ( !empty($show_count) )
            $link .= ' (' . intval($category->count) . ')';

        if ( 'list' == $args['style'] ) {
            $output .= "\t<li";
            $class = 'cat-item cat-item-' . $category->term_id;
            if ( !empty($current_category) ) {
                $_current_category = get_term( $current_category, $category->taxonomy );
                if ( $category->term_id == $current_category )
                    $class .=  ' current-cat';
                elseif ( $category->term_id == $_current_category->parent )
                    $class .=  ' current-cat-parent';
            }
            $output .=  ' class="' . $class . '"';
            $output .= ">$link\n";
        } else {
            $output .= "\t$link<br />\n";
        }
    }
}
array(
    'title_li' => '',
    'depth' => 1,
    'walker' => new Custom_Cat_Walker()
)
wp_list_categories( $args );
```

Comment: but htat don't work. only i want add text before category in each category li

Comment: BTW you probably should use [`get_categories`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories), which gives you a unformatted result to work with. @VektorUnbreakable

Comment: Look, with that code i have this http://www.buscatuppersex.com/ (see sidebar top category list). I want show Tuppersex A Coruña / Tuppersex Álava... Tuppersex before each category. @ialocin

Comment: the code works, only i want add "tuppersex" before each category @ialocin

Comment: that works but show all children categories and i only want first level. Why echo=0&title_li=&depth=1&hide_empty=0&exclude=1,762,899,951 don't work in this code?

Comment: a quick look at the [source](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.7.1/src/wp-includes/category-template.php#L480) shows that the depth parameter is used by [walk_category_tree](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.7.1/src/wp-includes/category-template.php#L731), so maybe the easiest solution would be using a custom category_walker @VektorUnbreakable